# How I can Fix ( no matching function for call to 'Hospital::Hospital()'| )

Tags: c++

This code is for Hospital record homework and I tried to solve it but there is a compilation error.

error line is : ( Hospital hs [3]; ) and I wrote error text at the last .

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Hospital
{
private:
    string name ;
    int beds ;
    int patients ;

public :
    Hospital(string name , int beds , int patients)
    {
        if (beds >= 0)
        {
            beds = beds;
        }
        else {
            beds = 0 ;
            cout << " Eror : Number of beds must be grater than or equal zero !! " << endl ;
        }
        if(patients >= 0 )
        {
            if (patients <= beds)
            {
                patients = patients ;
            }
              else
        {
            cout << "Eror : Number of patients must be smaller than or equal beds !! " << endl ;
        }

        }
        else
        {
            cout << " Eror : Number of Patients must be grater than or equal zero !! " << endl ;
        }
     }
     void addpatient()
     {
         if (patients +1 <= beds)
         {
             patients += 1 ;
         }
         else
         {
             cout << "Hospital is full !! " << endl ;
         }
     }
     void removepatient()
     {
         if(patients > 0 )
         {
             patients -= 1 ;
         }
         else
         {
             cout << " Eror : The Patients is already Zero !! " << endl ;
         }
     }
};
int main()
{
Hospital hs [3];
hs[0] = Hospital("King Salman" , 3 , 0);
    hs[1]= Hospital("King Saud" , 3 , 4) ;
        hs[2]=Hospital("Alhabib" , -8 , 4 );

hs[0].addpatient();
hs[0].addpatient();
hs[0].addpatient();
hs[1].removepatient();
hs[2].addpatient();
hs[1].addpatient();
hs[0].removepatient();

    return 0;
}
```

**output error**

> no matching function for call to 'Hospital::Hospital()'

Comment: Just put `Hospital() = default;` in your class definition.

Comment: Google 'C++ constructors'

Comment: The compiler may have issues with assignments like 'beds = beds;'.  Which beds are what?

Comment: If you actually declare the ctor in your class, you could put it in a header file and authors of other modules would know how to call it without requiring the cpp:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way

```
Hospital hs [3] = { 
    Hospital("King Salman" , 3 , 0), 
    Hospital("King Saud" , 3 , 4),
    Hospital("Alhabib" , -8 , 4 )
};
```

or you could add a default constructor to your class.